# Laravel Scope querying to count project type for each user

Tags: laravel, model

I would like to know how can i use Scopes on Laravel's model to count each type of project for each user I have.

Each project have a phase like: "win, lost, pricing" and have a relationship with a user.

I want to know how many projects each user have by the type like:

User1: win 2
       pricing 5
       lost 0

User2: win 2
       pricing 1
       lost 3

**Table:**
[Projects table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pA9Db.png)

**Project Model:**

```
protected $table = 'projects';
protected $fillable = ['name', 'phase', 'estimated_date', 'user_id','client_id', 'comments', 'docs', 'approved_docs','contact_id'];

public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'user_id')->withTrashed();
}
```

**

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
<?php 
User::with(['projects' => function($q){
                return $q->groupBy('projects.phase')
            ->select(\DB::raw("count(*) as count"), 'user_id');

            }])->get();
```

Id you want scope then in user.php create :

```
<?php 

public function scopePhasecounts($query){
                return $query->with(['projects' => function($q){

                    return $q->groupBy('projects.phase')
                    ->select(\DB::raw("count(*) as count"), 'user_id');
                }])
            }
```

and then you can do

```
User::phasecounts()->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

For better understanding of the problem, show your db table schema for **project**

With the little information your provided, something like this could work...

**Project Model:**

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use App\User;

/**
 * Assumption: You have a table field called **phase** on the project model.
 */
class Project extends Model
{
    /**
     * The relationship: A project belongs to a user.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    /**
     * Query for WINs.
     */
    public function scopeWin($query)
    {
        return $query->where('phase', 'win);
    }

    /**
     * Query for PRICINGs.
     */
    public function scopePricing($query)
    {
        return $query->where('phase', 'pricing);
    }

    /**
     * Query for LOSSes.
     */
    public function scopeLost($query)
    {
        return $query->where('phase', 'lost);
    }

    /**
     * Query for total number of projects.
     */
    public function totalCounts()
    {
        $wins_count     = $this->win->count();     // call to scopeWin($query)
        $pricings_count = $this->pricing->count(); // call to scopePricing($query)
        $losses_count   = $this->lost->count();    // call to scopeLost($query)

        $total_project_counts = $wins_count + $pricings_count + $losses_count;

        return $total_project_counts;
    }
}
```

**User Model:**

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Project;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The relationship: A user has many projects.
     */
    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Project::class);
    }

    /**
     * Total projects for this user.
     *
     * Using existing relationship instance, 
     * make a call to the appropriate method on the project model.
     */
    public function totalProjectCounts()
    { 
        return $this->projects()->totalCounts();
    }

    // User projects with phase Win.
    public function projectWinCounts()
    { 
        return $this->projects()->win()->count();
    }

    // User projects with phase Pricing.
    public function projectPricingCounts()
    { 
        return $this->projects()->pricing()->count();
    }

    // User projects with phase Lost.
    public function projectLostCounts()
    { 
        return $this->projects()->lost()->count();
    }
}
```

For a given user you can check for individual totals like so:

```
$user->totalProjectCounts(); 

auth()->user()->totalProjectCounts(); 

Auth::user()->totalProjectCounts();
```

Hope this helps. Otherwise provide more info about the issue you're facing.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th> USER </th>
        <th> WIN </th>
        <th> PRICING </th>
        <th> LOST </th>
        <th> TOTAL </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach ($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->projectWinCounts() }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->projectPricingCounts() }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->projectLostCounts() }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->totalProjectCounts() }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

I think **belongsTo(User::class)** is more appropriate instead of **hasOne(user::class)**.

Comment: I edit the question and add more info.

I want to display on a table the number of projects for each phase that each user have